# Windows Phone 8 Emulator doesn't connect to internet in Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

Previously I was using Visual Studio 2012 (including Update 2) with Windows Phone SDK 8.0 in Windows 8. Everything was fine and emulator connected to internet as expected without any additional settings.

But later in same machine I installed Windows 8.1 and set up same environment with Visual Studio 2012 (including Update 2 and 3) with Windows Phone SDK 8.0. Only additional thing was Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 as it is required in Windows 8.1

Now my Windows Phone 8 doesn't connect to internet. It doesn't give any error messages and just doesn't load any web page in mobile internet explorer. I'm using mobile broadband dongle to connect to internet.

There are several discussion regarding internet issue in wp8 emulator but non of them talk about this specific issue comes with Windows 8.1

Is there anyone who had same problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the bridged connections created by Hyper-V got removed/changed. If suitable I would suggest you remove the WP 8.0 SDK and then install it again and see if it solved the issue.
Optionally you can try to fiddle with the 'Virtual newtork...' adapters in Hyper-V to fix this, but I'm not help there as I didn't manage to solve it that way.

Cheers,
Manuel